# Prime ideal generated by two quadratic polynomials

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals

Let $q_1$ and $q_2$ be two irreducible quadratic homogeneous polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$.

Consider the ideal $\langle q_1, q_2 \rangle$.

When this ideal   is prime?

I am interesting in necessary or sufficient conditions.

Comment: the resultant of $q_1$ and $q_2$ w.r.t. any $x_j$ should be irreducible, I gather, otherwise the ideal would not be prime...